# export-csv is destroying my date-formats

Tags: powershell, csv, datatable

In powershell, I create a datatable; there's a column in the datatable, with formatted date:

```
SELECT RIGHT('0' + cast(day(GETDATE()) as varchar(2)),2) + '-' + CAST(DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(3)) + '-' + cast(DATEPART(year, GETDATE()) as varchar(4))
```

So the actual value is: dd-MMM-yyyy

Except, when I use the following, the date format is changed to dd-MMM-yy

```
$dtResult | export-csv $outputFile -notypeinformation
```

it is crucial to get the date as dd-MMM-yyyy

cheers

Comment: Can you show the code that is creating the datatable? Is this any use, as a way to temporarily set one of the datetime formats for the current session - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14910743/478656 - then maybe export-csv will use that format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the date is stored in the data table as a DateTime, so it will use the system default for formatting. One way around this is to convert the datatable to a collection of objects first, converting the date to a string in the process:

```
$dtObjects = $dtResult | Select-Object ID, Name, @{n="DateField";e={$_.DateField.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"}}
```

Replace the field names with your actual field names.

Comment: thanks; I tried your suggestion; but the date is still in the "yy" format, rather than "yyyy"; this is how I'm doing it: $dtObjects = $($dtResult | Select-Object @{n="Trade Date"; e={ $(([datetime]$_.TradeDate).tostring("dd-MMM-yyyy")) }})
        $dtObjects | export-csv $outputFile -notypeinformation

Comment: Are you seeing the wrong date format when looking at the raw csv file, or upon importing it into Excel, or some other application?

Comment: the wrong date format only shows up when I open up the .csv file (after the export). The actual values in the original data-table and the new collection of object are all valid. It's the export bit that's causing the issue

Comment: How are you opening the csv file? In a text editor, or in Excel? Because Excel tends to format anything it thinks are dates.

Comment: oh boy, you're right! I was opening it with excel. Using a normal text editor, all the values are correct!!

Comment: let me see if the other guys on the other side are ok with what we're sending them.... this could be it... I'll let you know as soon as I do :)

Comment: I'm marking this as answered regardless of what the other guys say; thank you so much for your clever inputs!! :)